# Функция определения возраста

Tags: javascript, дата

Есть код:

```js
let years = [];

for (let i = 2022; i >= 1900; i--) {
    years.push(i);
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        birth_day[i] = new Option(i, i);
    }

for (let i = 1; i <= years.length - 1; i++) {
        birth_year[i] = new Option(years[i], years[i]);
    }


birth_date.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

    let target = e.target;
    let birth = new Date(`${birth_month.value} ${birth_day.value}, ${birth_year.value}`);
    if (birth == 'Invalid Date') {
        return null;
    }
    let full_date = new Date();


    let new_age = +full_date.getFullYear() - +birth_year.value;

    if (full_date.getMonth() <= birth_month.value && full_date.getDay() < birth_day.value) {
        new_age = new_age - 1;
    }
    let lidx = new_age.toString()[new_age.toString().length - 1];
    let alidx = new_age.toString()[new_age.toString().length - 2]
    if (alidx + lidx >= 11 && alidx + new_age.toString()[new_age.toString().length - 1] <= 14) {
        age.innerHTML = `${new_age} лет`;
    } else if (lidx >= 2 && lidx <= 4) {
        age.innerHTML = `${new_age} года`;
    } else if (lidx == 1) {
        age.innerHTML = `${new_age} год`;
    } else {
        age.innerHTML = `${new_age} лет`;
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="birth_date">
  <select name="birth_day" id="birth_day">
  <option value="day">День</option>
</select>
<select name="birth_month" id="birth_month">
  <option value="month">Месяц</option>
<option value="0">Январь</option>
<option value="1">Февраль</option>
<option value="2">Март</option>
<option value="3">Апрель</option>
<option value="4">Май</option>
<option value="5">Июнь</option>
<option value="6">Июль</option>
<option value="7">Август</option>
<option value="8">Сентябрь</option>
<option value="9">Октябрь</option>
<option value="10">Ноябрь</option>
<option value="11">Декабрь</option>
</select>
<select name="birth_year" id="birth_year">
  <option value="year">Год</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>
<span>Возраст: <span id="age">XXX</span></span>
```

Проблема такая: при смене месяца не меняется возраст.

Попробую объяснить суть проблемы, поскольку проверка ведёт себя довольно странно.

Сегодня 3 августа 2021 года. Есть дата рождения, 2 августа 2001, например. Отображается возраст 20 лет. Когда меняю 2 на 4, то возраст меняется на 19 лет (пока ОК). Меняю месяц на июль (4 июля 2001) и возраст обратно меняется на 20 лет (пока ОК). Потом снова возвращаюсь к 2 августа 2001, возраст остаётся как был, на 20, всё ОК. НО, когда я меняю на сентябрь (2 сентября 2001), вот тут проблема - возраст не поменялся, а должен был поменяться на 19, поскольку ДР не было ещё. То же самое с октябрём и остальными месяцами до конца года, но когда меняю месяц на более ранний, всё нормально работает. Зато когда меняю день снова на 4 (4 сентября 2001, т. е. на число дня больше сегодняшнего) - возраст меняется на 19, и в этом проблема, поскольку возраст должен был поменяться при смене месяца (август на сентябрь или август на октябрь). Но не меняется, и я не понимаю, почему.

Пытался делать разные проверки, но всё равно не работает как надо, и даже хуже. Что не так делаю, где я ошибся? Уже совсем запутался, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const now = new Date();

// Проблема тут:
const createDateLikeABoss = 
  new Date(`${now.getMonth()} ${now.getDate()}, ${now.getFullYear()}`);

console.log(now.toGMTString(), '<>', createDateLikeABoss.toGMTString());
```

Вы выбрали очень странный формат для того, чтоб сделать дату. И работает он соотвествующе. Месяц "8" при парсинге даты из такого формата считается августом, тогда как getMonth август - это 7 (как у вас в селекте). А вы их сравниваете между собой.

Comment: Про getMonth слышал, что отсчёт месяцев начинается от нуля и поэтому август седьмой. Вот только не понимаю, что именно у меня сравнивается и каким образом. Значение из селекта и значение даты? Или что? Сорри, я просто совсем слаб в этом вопросе, не думал, что с датами столкнусь таким образом.

Comment: @AntAnt Всё верно, getMonth в качестве августа выдаст цифру 7. У вас в селекте так же, август - 7. Но вот когда вы генерите дату из значений, вы используете формат, в котором 7 это июль

Comment: в общем я поколдовал немного, теперь вроде работает. codepen.io/Antaeothe/pen/oNWMMaX Просто до меня не сразу дошло что виноваты во всём значения (генерируемые значения, которые Вы упоминали), вводимые внутри объекта Date() в переменной birth. Так же изменил немного условие. Спасибо большое за помощь. :)